# textarea data not inserting completely

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to make an admin page where the admin can edit his 'about us' page description and image, to be displayed into the website.

I am storing the description from `textarea` and image from image upload in the database. But the description is not inserting completely in the database. So the about us page in the webpage is displaying incompletely. I have changed my description field in the database from `varchar` to `text`, `longtext`, `blob`, `longblob`.

I have also tried increasing the length but the insertion is still incomplete. It is displaying about 150 words - not more.

Comment: Which data type are you used for description?

Comment: You've attempted longtext and still the max it displays is 150 words? (so about 1000 chars?)

Comment: i have tried with varchar and increasing its length but it is not inserting completeley.

Comment: oh! try with text data type and then check..

Comment: You say that you have checked the database field for length and data type, but how is the data getting into the database? Is there a length set on the data access or stored proc?

Comment: yes i have attempted long text but it is still not inserting completely.

Comment: @RyanH i am inserting it through a textarea.

Comment: post the HTML for your textarea, as well as the code that processes that data and inserts it into the DB. Also please post the table definition.

Comment: @Sadikhasan thank you the text worked :)

Comment: Thank you everyone for helping out.

Comment: In your question you say you already tried `text` as data type and in the comments you say that this data type helped you in the end?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using [`text` or `blob`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/blob.html) as data type for your description texts.